# Chrome: Network tab doesn't scroll automatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I updated Chrome to v104.0.5112.81 from v103. And now Network tab doesn't scroll automatically. The tab has always been zommed out, but even with the original or zoomed in size, it doesn't want to scroll properly. There is always a space between scroll bar and the bottom arrow. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPK81.jpg 
I've tried making the dev tool panel wider/narrower/shorter/longer, but nothing helps.

Comment: Try to close the Console tab. Maybe helps. Also, check if this bug has already been reported and/or if you want, you can report it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: It's a bug in devtools: https://crbug.com/1349531